# Combine jQuery to simplify simpleModal call?

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I am using SimpleModal to trigger multiple modals on a page.  The jQuery looks like this:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#basic-modal .basic').click(function (e) {
        $('#basic-modal-content').modal();

        return false;
    }); 
});
```

However, I have multiple modals on a page, each with a different ID...  such as:

```
#basic-modal_2
#basic-modal-content_2 
#basic-modal_3
#basic-modal-content_3
```

Etc...

I can achieve this by just adding more jQuery such as:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#basic-modal .basic').click(function (e) {
        $('#basic-modal-content').modal();

        return false;
    }); 

   $('#basic-modal2 .basic').click(function (e) {
        $('#basic-modal-content2').modal();

        return false;
    }); 
});
```

But this is wildly inefficient.  Is there a way I can just look for the the end of the ID with one call rather than repeating the same thing with different IDs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the id of the modal in the `data-modal-id` attribute of `.basic`

```
<div id="basic-modal" >
   <div class="basic" data-modal-id="basic-modal-content">

   </div>
</div>

jQuery(function($) {
    $('.basic').click(function(e) {

        var id = $(this).data('modal-id');
        $('#' + id).modal();

        return false;
    });
});​
```

Comment: This is pretty close to what I'm looking for - however, the basic-modal-content ID has some CSS rules applied to it.  When I change the ID from ID="basic-modal-content" to data-modal-id="basic-modal-content" my CSS blows up.  Anyway around this?

Comment: Let the id remain the same .. Just add the extra data-attribute to the corresponding .basic class which holds the id of the corresponding modal